# Access iterater object value cplus plus

Tags: c++, iterator, breadth-first-search

I am trying to implement bfs in c++. In order to do this, I have created a variable called closedList which is supposed to keep the states that I have visited already. However in debugging, when I go and try to print the states in the closed list using an iterator, it says.

```
cannot convert ‘std::deque<state_t, std::allocator<state_t>>::iterator* {aka std::_Deque_iterator<state_t, state_t&, state_t*>*}’ to ‘const state_t*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘ssize_t print_state(FILE*, const state_t*)’    print_state(stdout, &it);
```

here is the code:

```
    for (std::deque<state_t>::iterator it=closedList.begin();it!=closedList.end();++it) {
    print_state(stdout, &it);       
        }
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not enough information, but you probably need `*it` instead of `&it`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are dereferencing your iterator incorrectly

```
print_state(stdout, &it);
```

You would use the `*` operator

```
print_state(stdout, *it)
```

And judging by the signature of `print_state`

```
print_state(FILE*, const state_t*)
```

It looks like it should actually be

```
print_state(stdout, &(*it))
```